# SQL Server: Alternative of long CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a very long `CASE` statement and it makes the query very long. Is there an alternative way? Does the long `CASE` statement impact the performance? I see people are recommending `COALESCE` but I'm not sure if this is a good alternative in my query.

The example below, a, b, c, d, e, f are columns from a table but I'm just using the letter here to make an example.

```
UPDATE table
SET totalAmt = CASE   
                 WHEN product_id = 1  THEN a*b*c*d
                 WHEN product_id = 2  THEN c*d*e + 1
                 WHEN product_id = 3  
                   THEN 
                     CASE WHEN term = 12 THEN b*c*d*e ELSE a*b*e*f END
                 WHEN product_id = 4   THEN a+b+c+d
                 etc.....
               END
FROM table
```

Comment: The performance impact of a case expression is probably not something you need to worry about. And a `coalesce()` is just a shorthand case expression anyway.

Comment: Are you sure all of the cases are as simple as you depict? I have a feeling that at least one of the cases and probably multiple also have select statements in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't expect any performance issues from the `CASE` statement itself.  Since your one query is making one pass at the data, it might perform much better than multiple queries for each product ID.

The query may perform better with a `WHERE` clause-- if that is even possible with your long query.

If the table is large, and it is indexed by product id, and the query is updating a small subset of products, you might get better performance breaking the query apart into separate `UPDATE` queries per product_id.  Otherwise you may end up with a table scan on a huge table.  For example:

```
UPDATE table SET totalAmt = a*b*c*d WHERE product_id = 1
UPDATE table SET totalAmt = c*d*e + 1 WHERE product_id = 2
```

If all the cases depend on `product_id`, then you could abbreviate the syntax like this:

```
CASE product_id
    WHEN 1 THEN a*b*c*d
    WHEN 2 THEN ...
END
```

I would recommend using comments to make the code more readable.  For example, if the products are a hard-coded set of known IDs, you might specify what they are.  Similarly, it may help future code maintenance to explain the calculation:

```
UPDATE table
SET totalAmt =
    CASE WHEN product_id = 1 -- table
    THEN a*b*c*d             -- some explanation of calculation
    CASE WHEN product_id = 2 -- chair
    THEN ...
```

Comment: Thanks Paul.  This way looks neater.

Answer (score 1):

If the `UPDATE` doesn't need to run against every record, you can use `WHERE` to filter.  As for your `CASE` expression, nothing springs to mind, I took out the nested `CASE` just out of my own preference, but don't think it has any performance impact:

```
UPDATE table
SET totalAmt = CASE WHEN product_id = 1 THEN a*b*c*d
                    WHEN product_id = 2 THEN c*d*e + 1
                    WHEN product_id = 3 AND term = 12 THEN b*c*d*e 
                    WHEN product_id = 3 THEN a*b*e*f
                    WHEN product_id = 4 THEN a+b+c+d
                 etc.....
               END
FROM table
WHERE product_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I'm very fond of taking out nested `CASE` statements like this. It may be worthwhile to point out explicitly *why* this works, that `CASE` statements "short circuit" once they have the true condition. Taking out nested cases can be a huge boon to readability, imo.

Comment: @Hart, I like this way that you show me.  It will be useful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative way?

Normally I would recommend a lookup table and a JOIN, but that only works with simple substitution (WHEN product_id = 1 THEN 'name'), and not calculations.

You could also split this up to a..f six UPDATE statements with a WHERE product_id = x, then test the above UPDATE and the six individual ones for performance differences.  Offhand though I don't see any benefit, unless we're talking a huge amount of rows.