# Query multiple columns with single statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have a table with a pivoted code value, Code1, Code2, etc up to Code100.
I have set of values (1,2,3,4,5,6) that I need to compare each code to.  Is it possible to scan a set of columns for a particular value without having to write out a massive case statement?

```
CASE WHEN Code1 IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN 'yes'
     WHEN Code2 IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN 'yes'
     WHEN Code3 IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN 'yes'
     etc
```

Comment: You can build your query dynamically.

Comment: Well depending on the dataset you can unpivot it and check it once. You could use a cursor but will possibly suffer some performance drawbacks but maybe not using FAST FORWARD compared to this massive case statement

Comment: 5 million records so would rather not unpivot

Answer (score -1):

You could [pivot the table first](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/580181).

Then process each record, in another select by turning those columns into a row.

This would require only one statement if done right.

CASE WHEN Value IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN 'yes'

:Updated

You could also try [a lookup table and a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28839120/5708555). If your all out of pivots.

Comment: The table is pivoted.  UnPivoting is what you mean, and i'm reluctant to do that because I already have 5 million records